# Finding Singular points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f = 3x^3 + 3x^2 − y^2 + z^2$, $g = 3x^2 + 4^x + 3y^2 + z^2$ be polynomials
in $\mathbb{C}[x, y, z]$ and let $W = V(\langle f, g\rangle) ⊂ \mathbb{A}^3(C)$. By using the Jacobian matrix, find the singular points of W or show that it has no singular points.(You may assume without proof that $\langle f, g\rangle$
is a prime ideal therefore $W$ is an irreducible variety and $I(W) = \langle f, g\rangle)$

I have $f_x=9x^2+6x$, $f_y=-2y$ and $f_z=2z$

and $g_x=6x+4$, $g_y=6y$, $g_z=2z$

so $J=\begin{bmatrix}9x^2+6x&-2y&2z\\6x+4&6y&2z\end{bmatrix}$

I don't know how to find the singular points (or show that it has none)

Comment: A quick search of stack exchange unearths several highly relevant posts which illustrate the methods you need (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137856/finding-singular-points-and-computing-dimension-of-tangent-spaces-only-for-the?rq=1) ). If you're looking for more specific guidance, please provide information about what you know and why you are confused (see ["How to ask a good question"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for general guidelines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point on $W$ is singular if and only if the rank of the Jacobian matrix at this point is $\leq 1$, which is (by basic linear algebra) equivalent to the fact, that all $2 \times 2$-minors vanish.

Hence you should compute the three $2 \times 2$-minors and see where they will vanish simultaneously.